# Use a List in http.get()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a List which has URLs inside it. I want to use `http.get()` to read these URLs. I've tried to use `http.Client()` but i did not know what to parse in.

My function:

```
   List url = listear ; // <- URLS 
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
var document = parse(response.body);
var items = document.querySelector("body");
setState(() {
  valueee = items.innerHtml;
});
```

Comment: Look this :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331782/flutter-send-json-body-for-http-get-request

Comment: Your response body is html or json ?

Answer (score 0):

Use your get method multiple times, each per one request like this:

```
...
var response = [];
for(final e in url){
  response.push(await http.get(e));
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Future.wait()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html) with [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists), like this :

```dart
List<http.Response> results = await Future.wait([for(var url in urls) http.get(url)]);
for (var result in results) {
  var document = parse(result.body);
  var item = document.querySelector("body");
  setState(() {
    valueee += item.innerHtml;
  });
}
```

Comment: how can i then use  parse (from html/parser.dart) to do document.outerHtml or results.querySelector

Comment: I do not know these packages but I'm sure you can use them as previously inside a for-loop. I tried to write something that could help you but I don't really know what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: got an exception from item.innerhtml was called on null. Seems  like item or document dont return any value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers i made a new function from your answers.

```
  Future _initiate() async {
    List urls = [
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338520/use-a-list-in-http-get/60340538?noredirect=1#comment106745313_60340538',
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338520/use-a-list-in-http-get/60340538?noredirect=1#comment106745313_60340538'
    ];
    listii = [];
for (var url in urls) {
  listii.add(await http.get(url));

  for (var result in listii) {
    var document = parse(result.body);
    setState(() {
      valueee = document.outerHtml;
      print(' ');
      print(valueee);
      print(' ');
    });
  }
}


 }
```