# Send JSON body with HTTP get request

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to put JSON body query parameters into http.get request. I tried to even follow this [Flutter: Send JSON body for Http GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331782/flutter-send-json-body-for-http-get-request) but no luck there. No matter what I put into params variable I get all results from my backend. I have tested backend with postman and everything works fine

[image]

Here is my code in flutter

```
 Future<List<Country>> fetchCountries(String name) async {
    final token = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).token;
    final params = {"name": "Uk"};
    try {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(APIPath.findCountry());
      final newUri = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);
      print(newUri); //prints http://localhost:8080/country/find?name=uk
      final response = await http.get(newUri,
          headers: [APIHeader.authorization(token), APIHeader.json()]
              .reduce(mergeMaps));
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Iterable list = jsonResponse['result'];
        print(list);
        return list.map((model) => Country.fromJson(model)).toList();
      } else {
        throw HttpException(jsonResponse["error"]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Placing body into http.get request doesn't work as for http.post request. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to keep in mind.

1. The [HTTP RFC for method GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) says:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics...

It is a bad architectural style, to send any data in the body of GET request.

2. If you want to ignore that and still want to send body in the GET request, it makes sense to set content type header to "application/json".
3. The example you referred does not use body in the GET request. Instead, it retrieves parameter values from the given JSON object and puts them to a URL. Then this URL is called via GET without body.

**My suggestion:**

- If the number of URL parameters is relatively small and their values are short, so that the resulting URL is readable, use GET and URL with parameters.
- If the URL with parameters becomes hard to read, put parameters to the body and use POST.
- There are no precise criteria. It is a matter of your taste and your personal preferences. The readability of URL may be just one of criteria to consider when choosing GET or POST.

Comment: Thanks for response.. I'm sending `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in here `APIHeader.json()` but I'm still not able to add body into my get request so I thought I will follow the question in the link but that didn't work as well... Well I will then rework it to post request instead. I don't want to use parameters in my url because there is a lot of parameters.. well not exactly for this query but in others so I want to keep all of them in the body

Comment: I'm just going to say, "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics" and sending, a large JSON that defines the request in the body, doesn't mean its bad architectural style.  It just means exactly that, "no defined semantics".  It doesn't mean its in error to send JSON in the body of the GET request.