# Flutter/Dart http POST redirect send body via GET

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, dart-http

I'm trying to `POST` data to a Google Sheets web app.

When I `POST`data to the endpoint I get a status 302 back. If I then `POST` the data to the new location I get a status 405.

It works when I use Postman but I can't get it to work in Flutter.

Postman receives the 302 and then sends a `GET` request with my JSON payload as body. This seems to be against the `GET` specification but it works.

I tried the flutter HTTP package and DIO, both don't let me send a body via `GET`. I tried DIO with and without `followRedirects`.

How can I send a body via `GET` in flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use dio request instead

```
await dio.request(
  "/test",
  data: {"id": 12, "name": "xx"},
  options: Options(method: "GET"),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With dio configure your Options widget like following to avoid redirection for the first request:

```
Options(
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) {
          return status < 500;
        }),
```

GET is not intended to send data, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312720/10286880.

If you want to send them with POST you can do the following:

```
final res = await dio.post(
    '[YOUR ADRESS]',
    data: json.encode([YOUR BODY AS MAP])
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunately using POST does not work and I have to use GET. I don't know why it is implemented that way by Google since it is as you say against spec.